# Setting prettier sections order in .svelte file

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte, prettier

Whenever i save a .svelte component file in visual studio code
Prettier formatter is formating my file in this order:

- Script
- Style
- HTML Markup

I want to change the order of the sections to be:

- script
- HTML
- Style

How can i change the order of the sections?

Answer (score 4):

This should be the default sort order with [v2 of the Svelte Prettier plugin](https://github.com/sveltejs/prettier-plugin-svelte/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200). If you can, install the latest version of `prettier-plugin-svelte`.

If you can't update, you can use the `svelteSortOrder` setting in your [Prettier config](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html).

```json
{
  "svelteSortOrder": "scripts-markup-styles"
}
```